# Why can't a submit button send to PHP and jQuery at the same time?

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "" method = "POST" id = "form">
        <img src = "circle.gif" id="loading" style="display:none; "/>
        <input type="text" name = "text2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Send">
    </form>
<?
if (isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    echo $_POST['text2'];
}
?>
    <script>
        $('#form').submit(function(e) {
            $('#loading').show();
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to store in my db the value written in the textbox **using PHP**, and while it's being saved, I want to show a gif using jQuery, once the page is loaded, this gif should be removed.

Then, If I don't comment nothing, gif appears when submit button is submitted but echo fails.

If I comment the jQuery script, PHP echoes the vale written.

If I comment the PHP script, gif is shown but no echo of course...

How could I do what i'm asking. I know that my full script does until only showing the gif, but this without this I can't continue.

Comment: You can't do this without instead using an ajax request.

Comment: not possible. you're submitting a form, which means the browser will try to display the response of whatever script you submitted to. e.g. the loading page would vanish almost immediately. You'll have to convert the whole thing to a full-blown AJAX request, then redirect AFTER that request completes. while the ajax call is in flight, you display the loading pic.

Comment: ok, what i was suspecting, using ajax, which it's very difficult to adapt with the real script. could it be possible to use addClass, and this jquery script would add a class that contains a gif, and once page is loaded remove this class?

Comment: what you could do is addClass when on submit , then use javascript to submit the form.

Comment: @mpm this is what i've just done :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired behaviour, but you need to do it by submitting an AJAX request to the server and then handling the return value.  So basically you'd add this ajax request to the click or submit event of the form, and handle the behaviour and request via javascript.

Perhaps something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action = "formSubmitHandler.php" method = "POST" id = "form">
        <img src = "circle.gif" id="loading" style="display:none; "/>
        <input type="text" name = "text2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Send">
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#form').submit(function(){
                // Show the loading icon before the processing begins
                $('#loading').show();

                // Send the query/form details to the server
                jQuery.ajax({
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    success: function(results) {
                        // Now that the processing has finished, you 
                        // can hide the loading icon
                        $('#loading').hide();
                        // perhaps display some other message etc
                    }
                })
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```